# Email header is "malformed" when using sendmail command from php. Why?

Tags: php, sendmail, malformed

I'm having trouble with a sendmail command.

I'm pulling the values out of a database call, and they look good.
The mail command looks like this:

```
sendmail(urldecode($row['tracker']),urldecode($row['recipient']),urldecode($row['docurl']),urldecode($row['last_accessed']));

function sendmail($vtracker,$vrecip,$vrawurl,$viewed){
    $to = $vtracker;
    $subject = $vrecip . " has viewed the presentation you sent them.</br>";
    $body= "Full document url:  " . $vrawurl . "<br/>".
    "Time and Date Viewed:  :" .$viewed ;

    if (!mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
       echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
}
```

I echoed all the variables and they look ok:

```
$vtracker:  Bob ;
$vrecip : gregmcg@yahoo.com ;
$vrawurl : https://docs.google.com/a/advetel.com/present/edit?id=0Ac_KwUsBMiw8ZGN2Z3N3cDlfMTc3c2Jubng0Z2Q ;
$viewed : Mon, 20 Feb 2012 10:36:22 CST ;
```

I'm getting an error (retrieved from the error log on the server) that looks like this.

```
[error] [client 66.249.68.23] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/m/3/s/m3sglobal/html/broadband/missing.html
[Tue Feb 21 20:17:15 2012] [error] [client 70.113.8.83] Failed loading /usr/local/zo/4_3/ZendOptimizer.so:  /usr/local/zo/4_3/ZendOptimizer.so: undefined symbol: empty_string
[Tue Feb 21 20:17:17 2012] [error] [client 70.113.8.83] malformed header from script. Bad header=/home/content/m/3/s/m3sglobal/: Nitrofill_Presentation.php
```

Why is the header "malformed"?

Comment: That's not a sendmail command, it's a function you've written that happens to be named 'sendmail', and invokes PHP's own mail() function. Are you running PHP in CGI mode?  PHP in SAPI mode should never have a malformed header error.

Comment: You are assigning `$vtracker` to `$to` but, `$vtracker` shows a value of `Bob ;` but that is not a valid email address.  I think you have it switched with `$vrecip`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it wouldn't hurt to spend a bit more time with [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

Your `to` field is populated with `Bob`. That it not a legal address. The format of valid email addresses is quite complicated but these days, addresses generally are of the form `localpart@domain`. (Older formats that allowed delivery to [UUCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uucp) addresses via `%` username specifiers or `!` bang-paths are often not supported; further, `username@[<ip address>]` may or may not be supported on different servers or configurations. In general, there must be an `@` in an email address to separate the local part from the domain.)

You also appear to be using user-supplied data without any confirmation that it isn't performing [header injection attacks](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection). (See also the [suhosin project's documentation about `suhosin.mail.protect`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.mail.protect).)

Your `subject` field includes a `</br>`, which is pointless, since the `Subject:` header is interpreted as plain text. This field also appears to be using raw data supplied by the database.

The message body also includes the `</br>`, which is pointless, since your message does not include any [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) markup to indicate the presence of [`text/html` content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_email).

Comment: OK, I fixed the params and the breaks.  Here's the echo of the input fields, and the error message I get:  ZiFeCa75l greg.mcgee@advetel.com
gregmcgee@yahoo.com
https://docs.google.com/a/advetel.com/present/edit?id=0Ac_KwUsBMiw8ZGN2Z3N3cDlfMTc3c2Jubng0Z2Q
Mon, 20 Feb 2012 10:36:22 CST

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent. in /home/content/m/3/s/m3sglobal/html/nitrofill/tr/Nitrofill_Presentation.php on line 59

Line 59 is  
     if (!mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
     echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");}

Comment: You can't really code format within comments; they're just a throw-away deal. Best to edit your original question and add new content there.

Comment: I'm going to give up on this approach.  My web host (godaddy.com) provides a web form mailer that works.  I just have to get my data fields hooked up to it, which I've already got working.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @I_miss: hehehe, I can't blame you. It's a pity to be tied closer to godaddy, but there's no doubt that getting a mailer correct is subtle and complicated.